# Edit Block body content directly in database

Tags: 7, blocks, database

I've used some php code in a block that appears on all pages and now receive a fatal error and cannot access the site. In what table and field can I find the Block body content in the database for a Drupal 7 site? I plan to edit the Block body content directly in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

block_custom table is what you are looking for.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. The table is `block_custom` and the field is `body`

Comment: And `boxes` in Drupal 6